# Hacer que un div aparezca cuando hago focus a un input y desaparezca cuando de click en otro lugar que no sea el div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind

Tengo un elemento `div` que se aparece cuando a un `input` se le hace focus. Estoy trabajando con Tailwindcss.

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

El elemento `div` por defecto tiene la `className="invisible"` y cuando al `input` le hago focus este tiene una `className="visible"`
Quisiera que cuando haga click en otro lugar el (que no sea el `div`) el `div` desapareciera, osea que tenga una `className="invisible"`. He estado intentando hacerlo con `onBlur` pero esto no funciona como yo queria. Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto.

Codigo:

```
            <div className="w-56 relative h-10 ">
                <input
                    onFocus={() => setIsVisile(true)}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    className="bg-zinc-700 pl-10 pr-3 rounded-md placeholder:text-white outline-none w-full h-full"
                />
                {/**icon */}
                <FiSearch className="absolute top-[0.5rem] left-2 text-2xl" />
                <div
                    className={`w-96 ${
                        isVisible ? "visible" : "invisible"
                    } bg-zinc-600 absolute -bottom-[18.4rem] -left-20 min-h-[18rem] rounded-md flex items-center justify-center`}>
                    <span className="absolute top-1 left-1 text-xl">Recents</span>
                    <span>No recently searched</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Por que el `onBlur` no funciona como quieres? ¿Cuál es su defecto?

Comment: Porque, si uso el `onBlur` en el `input`, al momento de clickear en el cuadro que dice "Recents", este desaparece, lo que quisiera es que cuando clicke en el cuadro de "Recents", este no desapareciera. Sino que desapareciera cuando clicke fuera de ese cuadro o fuera del `input`. Espero hacerme entender.